# Post binary XML to a restful web service

Tags: r

I'm trying to post data to a restful web service that accepts XML with the request.

With the code below I can connect to the service but my XML data is not being recognised correctly by the service.  According to the API doc the xml needs to be encoded from text to binary.  I've read the RCurl docs but can't see how to do this.

```
url<-"https://serivce"

myheader=c(Connection="close", 
           'Content-Type' = "application/xml",
           'Content-length' =nchar(xml_data))

opts <- list(
  proxy         = "proxy", 
  proxyusername = "uname", 
  proxypassword = "password", 
  proxyport     = port,
  ssl.verifypeer = FALSE
)


data =  getURL(url = url,
               postfields=xml_data,
               .opts = opts,
               httpheader=myheader,
               verbose=TRUE)
```

Additional info

I wrote the xml data to an XML file with

```
xmlfile <- "myfile.xml"
saveXML(xmlTreeParse(xml_data,useInternalNodes=T),xmlfile)
```

How can I post this xml to the URL with RCurl?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134003/binary-data-posting-with-curl) should be a good start.

Comment: I'm still stuck.  Any extra help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems my code was working. I had to escape pesky character in the XML data.