# Translate the curl with data binary to php

Tags: php, curl

Is there anyone out there who is good with the PHP cURL functions and could possibly translate the following cURL call into the PHP functions?

I'm running into trouble replicating the "--data-binary @/var/www/html/images/request.png" portion into the various PHP options for cURL.

When I execute this **on CLI, it works perfectly**

```
curl -X POST --data-binary @/var/www/html/images/request.png http://127.0.0.1:4212/index/searcher
```

Here's my best try so far but it results in a corrupt image being uploaded:

```
<?php


$url = 'http://127.0.0.1:4212/index/searcher';
$header = array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data');
$fields = array('file' => '@/var/www/html/images/request.png');

$resource = curl_init();
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
$result = curl_exec($resource) ;
print_r($result);
curl_close($resource);

?>
```

Interesting part is the file in my system is **225873 bytes** whereas after upload it becomes **226062**.

Comment: I don't think `CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER` is used any more.

Comment: Yes, nothing changes even after deleting that.

Comment: edit your question to include file-size on source, vs what is captured on your local machine. Good luck.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31970541/php-curl-how-to-set-body-to-binary-data/