# How to post image and text using Php curl in html form

Tags: php, html, forms, rest, curl

How can i post image and text to a rest API using curl in html form i am able to post both image and text using postman to the same API but it not working in curl even when i try the same image and text i used in postman Here is the code of the form.

```
<form method="post" action="create.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>Name</label>
<input type ="text" name="name">
<input type="file" name="user_image" accept="image/jpeg" />
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

And here is the create.php script

```
$ch = curl_init();

$cFile = new CURLFile(['user_image']['tmp_name'], ['user_image']['type'], ['user_image']['name']);
$data = array('name' => $name, 'user_image' => $cFile);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "rest_api_url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Am able to post text without any issues but when i try to post with image nothing is been sent to the api endpoint.
PS: Am new to PHP so my process could be wrong am not sure thanks
Php script that handles the image

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["user_image"]["tmp_name"]) && $_POST["name"]){
        $tmp_file = $_FILES["user_image"]["tmp_name"];
        $img_name = $_FILES["user_image"]["name"];
        $upload_dir ="./Images/".$img_name;
        
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_cc(name, im) VALUES('{$_POST['name']}', '{$img_name}')";
        //
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $upload_dir) && $conn->query($sql)){
            $respone["Message"] = "Success";
        } else {
            $respone["Message"] = "Failed";
        } 
    } else {
            $respone["Message"] = "Invalid";
   }
```

Comment: It's a little hard for us to help you when we don't know where you are posting the image to. How is the destination where you post your image to handling the upload of that image?

Comment: @Niels I have update the question with the php script that handles the image and text upload

Comment: Have you checked if PHP has enough write permission to put images into that folder?

Comment: yes like i said am able to post correctly using postman both text and image which i don't think will be possible if there are permission issues.

Comment: @Serenity Is there any need to do curl to the other php code? I felt it's redundant. 2nd is are you already set the curl into post mode? https://stackoverflow.com/a/31995260/4906348

Comment: @BenyaminLimanto am not sure what other php code u are referring to am only using the curl in the create.php script

Comment: @Serenity if everything posts just fine, why do you need CURL is what he is asking?

Comment: @Niels thanks for the clarification really sorry pardon my confusion didn't realize i could send to the API script directly from the html form

Comment: @Serenity use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           1 );` rather than `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");`, I never seen any of that on php.net docs regarding customrequest...

Comment: @BenyaminLimanto thanks followed a tutorial guess it outdated