# How to POST Image/jpeg data with Curl from Terminal?

Tags: bash, shell

curl -v -s -w "Response_Time %{time_total} Response_Code %{http_code}\n" -X POST -H "Content-Type: image/jpeg" -H "Authorization: Bearer '$token'" -H "x-api-key: '$key'"'
-F "url=@https://api.ver/demo/img/jag-001.jpg"
https://www.example.com/v1/detectimage

I am getting bellow error.

- couldn't open file "https://api.ver/demo/img/jag-001.jp"
- Closing connection 0
  Execution result: Response_Time 0.881 Response_Code 000

Comment: There is no option to specify remote file via @url  for the -F option. See the manual page here - https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-F. If you just want to upload a binary file use the -d option. If you want to get the jag-001.jpg from a remote source consider getting it first via CURL and then feeding it to this command via PIPE/STDIN. Refer also to link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134003/binary-data-posting-with-curl

Comment: i am not getting clearly if u don't mine can u explain small example.