# Handling POST Request (JSON) in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, rest, post, oracle-apex-5.1

We are getting data `(JSON file)` from a middleware with a POST Request. 
Now I need to provide a URL for them to send their POST Request.
The data from the JSON file should then be saved in a database table.

I already tried it with this https://ruepprich.wordpress.com/2016/03/22/apex-rest-post/ but it is not working.

This is [my Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtQxw.png) it is simple and I think people can help me easily with this.

I already created a little program which sends the POST Request to a specific URL so I can test everything, but I just don't get the setup.
Has someone faced similar problems or can send me some resources about that? There are not that many related to APEX so help would be appreciated a lot.

Comment: take a look at this which is curl to post files : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134003/binary-data-posting-with-curl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test it using https://www.getpostman.com/ and you should get more details. Just reading your question is hard to know if your request is failing because of some missing setup, wrong path or something else.